# Partial derivative of $f(x,y) = \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ at $f_1(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

To be more precise than the title, the function is actually piecewise

$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y) \ne (0,0) \\
0 & (x,y) = (0,0) \\
\end{cases}
$$

I checked that the function is continuous at $(0,0)$, so I then calculated the partial derivative with respect to $x$ as

$$
f_1(x,y) = \frac{x^4-2xy^3+3x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \tag{1}
$$

This is undefined at $(0,0)$, so I then tried to find the limit around accumulation points. Let $S_1$ be the points on the $x$ axis

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f_1(x,0) = \frac{x^4}{(x^2)^2} = 1 \tag{2}
$$

Let $S_2$ be the points on the line $y = x$

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f_1(x,x) = \frac{x^4-2x^4+3x^4}{(x^2+x^2)^2} = \frac{2x^4}{(2x^2)^2} = \frac{1}{2} \tag{3}
$$

So, the limits are different around different accumulation points. That's where I'm confused because the answer should be $1$.

Comment: The partial derivative with respect to the first variable should consider the second variable fixed. In your last computations, you are considering the second variable non-fixed, and this is not compatible with the meaning of partial derivative with respect to the first variable.

Comment: @Crostul The computation in $(3)$ just plugs values for $(x,y)$ in the partial derivative already obtained in $(1)$. For your reassurance, SageMath also returns $\frac{1}{2}$ when differentiating with respect to $x$ and substituting $y=x$: `diff((x^3+y^3)/(x^2+y^2),x).subs(y=x)`

Comment: Why then answer should be $1$?

Comment: @PrettyAntlers I'm not saying that your computations are wrong: all these limits are correct, but it does not make sense to compute the partial derivative if then you consider a path where the second variable is not fixed.

Comment: @2000 The answer at the back of the book is $1$ but books have been known to be wrong and editors have been known to not publish errata, so you're quite welcome to suggest another answer if you can justify it :)

Comment: @Crostul The reason for the limits is that I was blocked where $f_1(x,y)$ was indeterminate at $(0,0)$. How should I proceed then?

Comment: Fix the second variable (in your case, since the point is $(0,0)$ you have to fix $y=0$). Then, you proceed by computing the limit (2), and you get the correct answer, which is $1$.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks for the explanation. Do I have to fix the variable that was not differentiated with respect to, or could I have fixed either variable?

Comment: You must fix the variable that was not differentiated with respect to. The reason is quite simple: partial derivatives are just special directional derivatives, where the path is exactly tha one fixing all other varibles. When you compute partial derivatives the path is fixed: it does not make sense consider other paths.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks again for the explanation, that's exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: How can $f(x, y) = 0$ if $(x, y) = (0, 0)$? The latter implies that $f(x, y) = \frac{0}{0} = 0^0$. If we take the limit $\lim_{n\to 0^+}n^n$ we see that it approaches $1$, thus $f(x, y) = 1$ if $(x, y) = (0, 0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of $f_1(x_0,y_0)$ you have :
$$f_1(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$$
So
$$f_1(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{h^3+0}{h^2+0}}{h}=1$$

Comment: Nice justification (re: comments under question)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Compute the limit (as $h$ goes to $0$) of  $(f(0+h,0)-f(0,0))/h$ to get the value of the partial derivative at $(0,0)$.

What you are looking at with those path limits is the question of continuity of this partial derivative function at $(0,0)$.

Comment: How can I evaluate the $f(0,0)$ part of your answer since it's indeterminate?

Comment: Aha, $f(0,0)$ is actually defined as $0$ if $(x,y) = (0,0)$.